# Why does my Python recursive function not break?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that should break once it fulfills a certain condition, ie when the isuniquestring(listofchar) function returns True, but sometimes it doesn't do that and it goes into an infinite loop. I tried printing the condition to check if there's something wrong with the condition, but even when the condition is printed true the function still continues running, I have no idea why.

one of the strings that throws up an infinite loop is 'thisisazoothisisapanda', so when I do getunrepeatedlist('thisisazoothisisapanda'), it goes into an infinite loop.

would be really grateful if someone could help
thanks!

Here's my code:

```
def getunrepeatedlist(listofchar):
    for ch in listofchar:
        if isrepeatedcharacter(ch,listofchar):
            listofindex = checkrepeatedcharacters(ch,listofchar)
            listofchar = stripclosertoends(listofindex,listofchar)
            print (listofchar)
            print (isuniquestring(listofchar))
            if isuniquestring(listofchar):
                return listofchar
                #print (listofchar)
            else:   
                getunrepeatedlist(listofchar)

    return listofchar
```

just for reference, these are the functions I called

```
def isrepeatedcharacter(ch,list):
if list.count(ch) == 1 or list.count(ch) == 0:
    return False
else:
    return True

def checkrepeatedcharacters(ch,list):
listofindex=[]
for indexofchar in range(len(list)):
    if list[indexofchar] == ch:
        listofindex.append(indexofchar)
return listofindex

def stripclosertoends(listofindices,listofchar):
stringlength = len(listofchar)-1
if listofindices[0] > (stringlength-listofindices[-1]):
    newstring = listofchar[:listofindices[-1]]

elif listofindices[0] < (stringlength-listofindices[-1]):
    newstring = listofchar[listofindices[0]+1:]

elif listofindices[0] == (stringlength-listofindices[-1]):
    beginningcount = 0
    endcount = 0
    for index in range(listofindices[0]):
        if isrepeatedcharacter(listofchar[index],listofchar):
            beginningcount += 1
    for index in range(listofindices[-1]+1,len(listofchar)):
        if isrepeatedcharacter(listofchar[index],listofchar):
            endcount += 1
    if beginningcount < endcount:
        newstring = listofchar[:listofindices[-1]]
    else: 
        #print (listofindices[0])
        newstring = listofchar[listofindices[0]+1:]
        #print (newstring)

return newstring

def isuniquestring(list):
if len(list) == len(set(list)):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: What is `isuniquestring`?  And for that matter, all the other functions you call?

Comment: uniquestring checks if the string has any repeated characters, isrepeatedcharacter checks if that character is a repeated character and it returns true or false, checkrepeatedcharacters checks for the indices of the the repeats of that character and returns a list, and stripclosertoends strips away all the repeated character that's closer to either end of the string. sorry for the initial vagueness, thought it would be too long to post the entire code here

Comment: @user3881923 The only thing that comes to mind here, is that either `checkrepeatedcharacters` at some point start comparing the character itself which means `stripclosertoend` never strips a single char. Or `stripclosertoend` starts malfunctioning at some point. Without seeing the code for those, it's unlikely people will be able to help you.

Comment: You missed the return for 'return getunrepeatedlist(listofchar)' near the end

Comment: @ljetibo thanks! I've added the other functions into my question, but the problem that concerns me is that i'm printing out the condition right before making my code test whether the condition, and sometimes the condition is printed True but the code doesn't stop running, and I'm not printing anything else, so I can't see what could have gone wrong in the middle :/

Comment: @danf omg thanks!! not really sure why but that seemed to solve the problem!!

Comment: --1 Indenting is vitally important in python. Your code is unrunnable in its current format, making answering this question impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that you are changing listofchar in your for loop. Try cloning that variable to a new name and use that variable for manipulations and return the new variable.